# Hyperlink in Trigger error message?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to include the hyperlink of the account in my trigger error message. But I am getting the error "Error: Compile Error: line 30:115 no viable alternative at character '\' at line 30 column 115". Pls tell me what is wrong here:

```
account.addError('This account already exists.The duplicate account is:'<a herf=\'https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ accName +'\'>Agency Name '+ accName + '</a>' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra apostrophe just before the anchor tag, and you're missing a closing parenthesis. Give this a shot:

```
account.addError('This account already exists. The duplicate account is: <a href=\'/'+ accName +'\'>Agency Name '+ accName + '</a>');
```

Also - to make this work you're probably going to want to pass in a Salesforce **ID** as part of your hyperlink, rather than the name of the Account.

Comment: And hard coding an instance url is bad practice. The anchor should be ...href="/' + acc.Id + '"...

Comment: If this answer worked like you say, then you should accept the answer. Also, Daniel, it'd be great to have you join us on the Area 51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce?referrer=4-k5FqV679TWbBGLxdLUKg2

Answer (score 0):

Your have a syntax error

```
account.addError('This account already exists.The duplicate account is:'<a href=\'https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ accName +'\'>Agency Name '+ accName + '</a>' ;
```

should be

```
String link = '<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ accName +'">Agency Name '+ accName + '</a>';
account.addError('This account already exists.The duplicate account is:'+link) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the account name is coming as it is. I need the account name to be hyperlinked so that user can click on it and go to its record. The error that i am getting now is:      "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
This account already exists.The duplicate account is:Agency Name (123)" I want the account name 123 to be hyperlinked.

Comment: The reason you weren't getting a link after fixing the syntax error was that you still had `herf` instead of `href` as per your original post.